# How detect when Extjs Grid lost focus

Tags: javascript, extjs

I need to listen to when extjs grid loses focus. I'm using extjs 1.1.1.

Comment: Yeah... good luck with that. I can't even find the docs for that version anymore

Answer (score 2):

If Ext 1.1.1's gridpanel has a blur event, you'll need to handle it from there.